# SSIS - Cannot insert the value null into column

Tags: ssis

I have seen this error before but got around it by entering values manually, but that was for 4 rows, this error occurs for over 100 rows this time.

The problem is, this column called `Shipto` it will have one of three things in it, a 1 digit number, a 2 digit number, or the word `All`. The import works perfectly fine for 1 and 2 digit numbers but when it has `All` it causes this error :

> *[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The
>   ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (162) failed
>   with error code 0xC0202009 while processing input "OLE DB Destination
>   Input" (175). The identified component returned an error from the
>   ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the
>   error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. 
>   There may be error messages posted before this with more information
>   about the failure.*

This package takes the values from one table and inserts them into another. I have looked at the table that it would be taking the values from, and the column `shipto` is not null.

The only difference is see is in the structure of the two tables. The temp table allows nulls on that column, where the real table does not. Both tables have the column as a `varchar(20)`.

I notice in the Data flow for this there is a check box that says `check constraints`; would unchecking this solve that issue? Because the column is not null.

Thanks for any help you can provide, and I will post any additional info that may be needed. Thank you.

Comment: "There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure" Are there any other messages? There usually are. Most of the problems I've seen are usually related to data type mismatches.

Comment: In the error message you shared, I do not see where it mentions the issue being a null value.  If the target table does not allow nulls, unchecking check constraints on your ETL package will not solve the issue.  You are certain there is not a null value in that column for any row in the source data?

Comment: @Samuel There are no other errors. The datatypes are the same, thats why I am confused on this.

Comment: @STLRick I am looking at the table now and not one row has a NULL value in the Column ShipTo. I don't understand how a populated column is being passed as a null value.

Comment: But the columns in the source and destination may not be because one accepts nulls and the other doesn't. Double click the source or destination tables, and look at the "columns" tab and check ShipTo for differences

Comment: Are there any transformations in the Data Flow between the source and the destination?

Comment: Just asking the stupid question, in the mappings tab of the destination, have you mapped one of the source values into the target column for shipto?  If there are no NULL values in the source data, and you're convinced it's a NULL issue, this is the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: @STLRick I was looking through the data flow, and that is exactly what I found. If you would like to get credit for the answer, just write out an answer and I will accept it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple possibilities:

1. There is a null in your source table.  Your target table does not allow null values in that column.  There are a couple options.  If you're using a data source straight from a table, use a SQL command instead and in the query, handle the null:

   SELECT field1, field2, isnull(shipto, '') field3, field4, .... 
   FROM Table

   You can use whatever you want in the empty string above to replace null values with a more acceptable value.

   If you don't want to do this, you will either have to allow nulls in the target database or figure out why there is a null in the source database table and make sure that no longer happens.
2. Fields are unmapped.  You have values in the source that are not mapped into the destination fields.
3. Other transformations between the source and destination are introducing NULL values.

Comment: Can you indicate which of these three answers worked for you so that someone else may benfit from the answer?  Thanks!